# How to log 2 different users into the same app without signing out one of them?

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin, .net-core, single-sign-on

My scenario uses SSO against Okta as an identity provider.

I have a mobile app that an employee uses to track items but with limited access to certain functions that only a supervisor can override.
What I would like to implement is something similar to any supermarket where the cashier is logged on the system but requires his supervisor to edit or remove items from the cart. Supervisors logging with a batch, makes the edit and the employee can continue his work without signing out.
How should I address this particular scenario where the action.
How this scenario can be applied on the web as well?

Comment: Sounds like you only want to authorise a single request. Maybe generate a single use code which you show the supervisor on their own UI, then type that in? Then you just need an authorize policy which applies to a user role, or by validating a well known query / post field?

Comment: the UI is the same for both users

Comment: The typical OAuth login, keeps the user details in the browser. If you don't control the login form, you can't do anything other than informing people to use a private / incognito window. "Single Sign On" is right there in the name.